# How to change a code from previous version to the last version( Julia)

Tags: julia

I have a code that is written by Julia V.03, I am learning Julia by the last version of that, I want to upgrade a code from V.03 to V/06 I actually don't know what should I do or what should I mention. Is there any guide for that? or What is different between these versions?

Comment: This question is too broad to be a good fit for StackOverflow (I'm voting to close). There have been many, many changes from v0.3 to v0.6, all of which are documented [here](https://julialang.org/blog/). If you don't want to read the release notes for each version, you could just run your code, see what breaks, and go from there.

Comment: No, not all of the changes are documented there. But all of the breaking changes are documented here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/NEWS.md

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lots of things have changed, but many of them have had good deprecations along the way.  If you have a large codebase, I think the best path forward here is to incrementally step through all the major releases — 0.4, 0.5, and 0.6.  While that may seem like 3 times the work, I think it'd actually be easier.  Many deprecation warnings tell you exactly how you should re-write your code to update it.  If you skip a release, you'll end up with much less helpful errors or the wrong behavior without warning.

There are also some breaking changes that did not get deprecations — you'll also want to follow along with the NEWS.md file for each release (or the archive in [HISTORY.md](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/HISTORY.md)) to ensure that you've also addressed the breaking changes that didn't get deprecations.